# Contacts geared for individuals or family info

Tags: gmail-contacts

It seems that the Google contacts are geared towards a single individual's information.  It is most difficult to keep all the information for a family.

Something like the following

```
John and Jane Doe  
Address  
Home Phone  
Anniversary 

His Pers EMail           Her Pers EMail  
His Birthday             Her Birthday  
His Cell Phone           Her Cell Phone  
His Office Phone         Her Office Phone  
His Office EMail         Her Office EMail
```

Is there anyway to do this easily ?
And send email to the personal email address and/or the office email addresses ?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into that problem, too.

You can add one or more "Person" values to a contact, with a person type (Spouse, Child, etc.). Then, if you use the version of Contacts accessible through Gmail, when you view a contact there is a "Find" link next to each person for that contact which will facilitate searching your contacts. (This doesn't currently work at www.google.com/contacts)

Another option would be to put the information in the rather copiously sized "Notes" field.

Comment: I use the "Notes" field to create a relationship. I create 2 separate contacts: one for Maria and one for Peter. Since they are married, I put the name of the spouse in the "Notes" field. So, if I search for "Peter Smith" in contacts, I get two results: Peter and Maria Smith.

Comment: That will also work if you use the "Person" fields.